# Instance of class in constructor

Tags: php, constructor, instance

I'm not sure with my approach. A have two classes and call functions of first class in second class like this:

```
class A {

    public function aClassFunction() {...}

}


class B {

    private $aClass;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->aClass = new A();
    }

    public function bClassFunction() {
        $test = $this->aClass->aClassFunction();
    }
}
```

It just works, but looks "suspiciously".

Comment: As you said: it works. But if you want you can just use [`extends`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) like: `class B extends A` and then you can use the function from the class A in class B

Comment: why not extend or better yet pass A as a dependency, through B's constructor? Theres even traits.. try abit more reasearch

Comment: I didn't know, how to explain it to google properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dependency injection in `B` class. That approach helps you mocking classes in test.

```
class B {

    private $aClass;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->aClass = $a;
    }

    public function bClassFunction() {
        $test = $this->aClass->aClassFunction();
    }
}

$b = new B(new A());
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks "suspiciously" like a dependency.  Why not Inject the Dependency?

```
class B {

    private $aClass;

    public function __construct($object) {
        $this->aClass = $object;
    }

    public function bClassFunction() {
        $test = $this->aClass->aClassFunction();
    }
}
```